# In Windows 8.1, does Consolidated mean Terminated?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

There is a new API in the Windows 8.1 ApplicationView namespace. The ApplicationView.Consolidated | consolidated event. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.consolidated.aspx)

> Description: Occurs when the window is removed from the list of recently used apps or if the user executes a close gesture on it.

MSDN docs are a little vague. Is this an API developers can use to detect when their application has been terminated by the user or by the system? What is a scenario to handle this event?

Comment: Is this another "honest question"?

Comment: Well, I don't know the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The consolidated event is only fired by secondary views created through MSApp.createNewView, and thus does not apply to the main view of the app--that is, it's not fired when the main app window is closed. It's only there to let the app as a whole know that one of its secondary views has been closed.

It's demonstrated in the [Multiple Views sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Multiple-Views-Sample-2582fcf3) and there's some lengthy commentary in the code on the matter.

The short of it is that there isn't an event other than suspending that occurs when an app is closed. You use the suspending event to do whatever you need.